# Threejs setting animation clip time (and mixer time) dont change animation

Tags: animation, three.js

I'm trying to control the animation interactively by changing the timescale, frame rate, etc... Those that i just mentioned i could get working just fine using the mixer. However, when i try to set where the animation currently is things don't seem to be working. Setting the mixer time as well as the animation action time does nothing to the animation does nothing.
That's how i'm trying to do it.

```
function animate(){
    var delta = sampling > 0 ? clock.getDelta() : 0;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    if(mixer)
    {
        mixer.time += delta; // does nothing. Using constants does nothing either
        mixer.update(delta); // Must have it or else the animation will bug. 
        action.time += delta; // does nothing. Using constants does nothing either
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Comment: See my [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55996913/559079). It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the lines:

`mixer.time += delta;`

`action.time += delta;`

Running `mixer.update(delta)` should update the `time` attribute of both the `mixer` and `action(s)` automatically.

There's more to it then manually changing the time attributes. In general it looks like manually updating the `time` attribute of both the `mixer` and `action(s)` is not supported.

If it's still not working, try `console.log(delta)` in your render loop and confirm it's non zero.